# Simple Login with DynamoDB

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

VERY new to DynamoDB. I can't seem to wrap my head around querying.How would I create a simple query to check if there is an entry in the table for "USERNAME" and "PASSOWRD" ?

```
UsersTable

int User ID;
string userEmail;
string createDeate;
string passwordSalt;
string passwordHash;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to locate an email. So you will have a table with a hash primary key and you will fetch for it with the `GetItem` API.

If you must have a UserId as the Primary key, you can set a GlobalSecondaryIndex on email and use the `Query` API for fetching the items.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not ideal, but I figured out a simple way to achieve this. create a userID field, and make it the md5 of the user's provided email;

So the process is:

user provides email and password
on the server-side the user's email address is turned into an md5
lookup the "user" record with a simple query using the md5